# detach and reattach rabbitmq consumer to the exchange

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a scenario where I need to detach a rabbitmq consumer from the exchange, on a specific event, so that it stops consuming the messages in the queue and then reattach the same consumer to the exchange and start consuming the messages again. I'm using Spring-RabbitMQ 1.6.

So far, I have read a few pages on the internet e.g. http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin

and http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#idle-containers and many others but couldn't exactly understand how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call `container.stop()` to stop the consumer; `start()` will restart it.

Comment: ok. but how to access the container ?? I guess I would need this class at my disposal "RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry" but I could not find a way to access it. I have RabbitAdmin and RabbitTemplate beans accessible to me.

Comment: You can get a reference to the registry using the usual Spring techniques (inject a constructor arg or property, `@Autowire`, `context.getBean()`, etc, etc) and stop/start that (it will stop all registered containers) or you can get individual containers from the registry using the `@RabbitListener` `id` and stop/start them. See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_container_management).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did some changes to the rabbitmq context xml and got reference of all the listeners via Collection<MessageListenerContainer> bean.

Comment: Is there a way that the consumers do not auto start on application startup and may be later when actually required !

Comment: got it !! added auto-startup="false" to listener-container